# Query- SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question that says Write a SELECT  statement to get a list of employees hired in the period from July 1998 to December 1999 . The list must contain the employee id  the  last and first name and the monthly salary – given that the table contains the yearly salary and that employees get 12 salaries per year.

I wrote this,but does not work:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY/12 as MONTHLY_SALARY
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIRE_DATE BETWEEN JULY-1998 AND DECEMBER-1999 ;
```

Comment: Mysql or SqlServer ?

Comment: What's the problem? What outcome do you get? Can you try putting a space between the / and salary as well as 12?

Comment: @scaisEdge SqlServer

Comment: I get this error ORA-00904: "DECEMBER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: How you can get an ORA- error  is sqlserver .. are  ..you playing?

Comment: I get this error using oracle sql developer.

Comment: Sqldeveloper seems different from sqlServer .. anyway  i have posted an answer hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be you have a wrong date format  (for mysql)

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY/12 as MONTHLY_SALARY
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIRE_DATE BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('07-01-1998, '%m-%d-%Y)  
       AND STR_TO_DATE('12-31-1999, '%m-%d-%Y) D ;
```

For sqlserver

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY/12 as MONTHLY_SALARY
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIRE_DATE BETWEEN Cast('07-01-1998'as datetime)  
       AND Cast('12-31-1999' as datetime) ;
```

And for ORACLE

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMPLOYEE_ID, SALARY/12 as MONTHLY_SALARY
FROM HR.EMPLOYEES
WHERE HIRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('07-01-1998' , 'MM-DD-YYYY')  
       AND TO_DATE('12-31-1999' , 'MM-DD-YYYY') ;
```